# Running and plotting Random Forest with categorical data as a feature vector in r

Tags: r, plot, random-forest

I have data as below. It has three columns. The first one is categorical data and the second column is numeric and the last one is my class label. I would like to run a random forest on my data and plot the tree as well as variable importance. my aim is to find which `subject_result` is the most important and followed by what and also see the tree.

using this code has an error

```
library(randomForest)  
randomForest(ENSC_Disc~.,data = df)

Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

similarly using rpart and ctree return error.

```
data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
   subject_result = c("ENSCPassed", "CHEMPassed", "ENSCPassed", "OTHERPassed",
                      "ENSCPassed", "MATHPassed", "ENSCPassed", "OTHERPassed",
                      "OTHERPassed", "OTHERPassed", "PHYSPassed", "CHEMPassed",
                      "MATHPassed", "ENSCPassed", "CMPTPassed", "OTHERPassed",
                      "CMPTPassed"),
     semester_num = c(9L, 4L, 16L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 11L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 3L,
                      11L, 8L, 11L, 12L),
        ENSC_Disc = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
)
```

Comment: Using this package exclusively?

Comment: `ENSC_Disc`should be `as.factor()`, as well as `subject_result`. Before calling `randomForest`, use `as.factor(df$ENSC_Disc)` and `as.factor(df$subject_result)`. Also random forest are made up with multiple trees, not just one.

Comment: Also a relevant post might be this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree

Comment: @NelsonGon, no any random forest package that offers the plot of the tree would be enough

Comment: @Cina how's this?

Comment: @NelsonGon, yes, it works. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt using `caret.`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
df<-data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
           subject_result = c("ENSCPassed", "CHEMPassed", "ENSCPassed", "OTHERPassed",
                              "ENSCPassed", "MATHPassed", "ENSCPassed", "OTHERPassed",
                              "OTHERPassed", "OTHERPassed", "PHYSPassed", "CHEMPassed",
                              "MATHPassed", "ENSCPassed", "CMPTPassed", "OTHERPassed",
                              "CMPTPassed"),
           semester_num = c(9L, 4L, 16L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 8L, 11L, 4L, 12L, 1L, 4L, 3L,
                            11L, 8L, 11L, 12L),
           ENSC_Disc = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)
)
set.seed(233)
str(df)
df$ENSC_Disc<-as.factor(df$ENSC_Disc)
fit.rf<-train(ENSC_Disc~.,data=df,metric="Accuracy",method="rf",
              trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=5))
```

First Variable Importance:

```
plot(varImp(fit.rf))
```

[image]

**The actual tree: This doesn't work as I think you expect. A better way is to use `library(rattle)` but this only works on "rpart" not "rf" but here goes:**

```
plot(fit.rf$finalModel)
```

[image]